# Format Cells Dialog Does Not Open

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a worksheet in which Format Cells does not open on any cell in the sheet:

•   It does open on other sheets in the same workbook.
•   The worksheet is not protected.
•   I saved it in current format - it is not in compatibility mode.
•   I tried copying the worksheet - problem exists on the copy.
•   I deleted all rows and columns from the copy - format cells still does not open.
•   Opened VB Editor in full module view and verified no code exists that might be hiding it for the worksheet.

Further, if I copy a single cell, any cell, from the sheet, to a new sheet, the new cell cannot 'format cells' on, while every other cell on the new sheet can be 'format cells' on.  This leads me to believe its some type of cell property.

What else could be causing this?

UDPATE:  If I remove all formatting from any given cell AND neighboring cells, the format cells is then available for that given cell.  So this is a cell property, but which?  I'd rather not remove all formatting to be able to edit format.

Comment: Does this happen for all actions; right-click, CTL+1 and Home Ribbon>Cells>Format? Does the problem still exist if you use the file on another computer?

Comment: Yes @ pnuts.  Yes, yes, yes, yes @ CharlieRB.  The problem seems to be in the sheet, not in the workbook, not in the file, not in the computer.

Comment: Further, if I copy a single cell, any cell, from the sheet, to a new sheet, the new cell cannot 'format cells' on, while every other cell on the new sheet can be 'format cells' on.  This leads me to believe its some time of cell property.